# Can't import .gzip backups to phpmyadmin

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm configuring a new VPS and after I exported the database from the the older server using **phpmyadmin** (and using gzip to compress it) I can't import it on the new server.

It states "You attempted to load file with unsupported compression (application/gzip). Either support for it is not implemented or disabled by your configuration.". I saw another post here but couldn't solve it yet.

It's under Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS and running phpmyadmin 3.3.2. Also it says in the upload dialog "Imported file compression will be automatically detected from: None, bzip2, zip" but I can't see gzip there.

I can't make the backup in another format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to fix it is to uncompress and recomposes the image.

```
gunzip <compressed_file>
bzip2 <extracted_file>
```

That should give you a .bz2 file to upload.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you did not install gzip on your machine.
Try to digit at command line:

sudo apt-get install gzip

Rememeber, before doing that update your system using

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember php has zlib support installed by default. You may have disabled it in your `php.ini`.

You might also use the following php script to determine which modules are being loaded:

```
<?php
   phpinfo()
?>
```

Comment: "Zlib support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to configure PHP --with-zlib[=DIR]" - http://us.php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php

Comment: As he is on ubuntu 10.04 server the deb packages shipped with the distribution are compiled with zlib support